# Unique attributes in "The Last Remnant"

Tags: the-last-remnant

Good day

Simple question, I notice that each character has unique attributes in The Last Remnant, but I cannot figure out what they affect.  The question is clear: what does the unique attributes affect in The Last Remnant? I am playing the Steam Version

Comment: Something tells me this question is hard-to-answer or unanswerable, or those stats have nothing to do with the game, just there to make the player get more of a feel about their character's personality traits :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good question. I had to dig a bit, but I found it on [the Wiki for The Last Remnant](http://lastremnant.wikia.com/) in the [FAQ](http://lastremnant.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ):

> **What is the effect of the unique attribute each unit has?**
>   The effects are all battle related, and most commonly they affect battle reassessment and character behaviour in certain situations. They don't apply outside of battle.

Comment: Thanks. I also did a lot of wiki jumping, couldn't find the answer :)

Comment: My pleasure. This game is criminally underappreciated, so I'm happy to help others get into it.

Comment: `criminally underappreciated` people are too scared of a little bit of difficulty